# svn: how to ignore folder except two files

Tags: svn, ignore, svnignore

How to ignore all subfolders of `submissions` except `one_file`?

```
submissions/
  vt1/
  vt2/
  vt3/
  one_file
```

`one_file` is already in the repo, `vt` folders are *not* in the repo.

(I was trying all below when outside of the folder `submissions`)

I tried `svn propedit svn:ignore .` with the subsequent `submissions/vt*`.
 Then did commit, just in case. This still shows all those vt folders when I call `svn status` (with `?` mark on them).

Then I tried the same propedit command but put there `submissions`. The same result. I also tried `submissions/*` and `./submissions/*`.

Then I tried to add just one of those vt folders (thus not using pattern `*`). It *still* shows that subfolder! Things become interesting...

I exhausted all my "logical" ways. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html):

> When found on a versioned directory, the `svn:ignore` property is
>   expected to contain a list of newline-delimited file patterns that
>   Subversion should use to determine ignorable objects in that *same*
>   directory.

You need to set the `svn:ignore` property on the `submissions` folder to `vt*`

From the directory in the working copy which is enclosing the `submissions` folder, use:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "vt*" submissions/
```

Or from the `submissions` folder itself, use:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "vt*" .
```

Comment: that worked, thanks so much! So, svn:ignore does not support _paths_ with nested folders?